# Bounds on measure of self-difference and $\epsilon$-neighborhood of convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I am trying to see how to prove Lemma 10.15 from Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability*:
[image]

Here $|B|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $B$, and $r(B)$ denotes the radius of the largest open ball contained in $B$.

I can see how to reduce both inequalities to the case where $B$ is compact. Then, for (i) I've tried relating $B$ to its Löwner-John covering ellipsoid, but from this I can only get the bound $|B - B| \leq (2d)^d |B|$, which is not good enough. For (ii) I've tried to sandwich $\partial_\epsilon B$ between two dilations of $B$ (based on the center of a ball with radius $r(B)$ contained in $B$), but this hasn't been successful so far.

Does anyone know how to prove these or where to find a reference for these types of results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) The set $B-B$ is called the *difference body* of $B$. The inequality $|B-B|\le \binom{2n}{n}|B|$ is due to Rogers and Shepard (*The difference body of a convex body*. Arch. Math., 8, 220–233, 1957). A proof can be found in the book *Convex bodies: the Brunn-Minkowski theory* by Rolf Schneider, Theorem 7.3.1. (The perusal of this book is highly recommended if you are interested in volume inequalities for convex sets.) The Rogers-Shepard inequality is sharp, with equality attained for any simplex, and its proof is tricky.

(ii) is a rougher estimate. Translate $B$ so that the largest ball it contains is centered at $0$. The set $(1+\epsilon/r(B)) B = B + (\epsilon/r(B)) B$ contains the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $B$, since $(\epsilon/r(B)) B$ contains a ball of radius $\epsilon$. The volume of $(1+\epsilon/r(B)) B$ is, of course, $(1+\epsilon/r(B))^d |B|$. Therefore, the "outer $\epsilon$-collar" of $B$, understood as the set of all points that do not belong to $B$ but lie within distance at most $\epsilon$ from it, has volume at most $((1+\epsilon/r(B))^d-1) |B|$. It remains to argue that the "inner $\epsilon$-collar" is smaller than the outer one, which seems obvious, but I don't have a proof right now.

**Addendum to complete proof of (ii)**: Define the inner $\epsilon$-collar as the set of points in $B$ with distance less than $\epsilon$ to $\partial B$. We must show that the volume of the inner $\epsilon$-collar is at most $((1 + \epsilon/r(B))^d - 1)|B|$. If $\epsilon/r(B) \geq 1$, then this is trivially true since in this case $((1 + \epsilon/r(B))^d - 1) \geq 1$ and the inner $\epsilon$-collar has volume at most $|B|$. So assume $\epsilon/r(B)<1$. Since $B$ is convex, we have $(1-\epsilon/r(B))B + (\epsilon/r(B))B \subseteq B$. Since $(\epsilon/r(B))B$ contains the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at the origin, this implies that each point of $(1-\epsilon/r(B))B$ has distance at least $\epsilon$ to $\partial B$, so that $(1-\epsilon/r(B))B$ does not intersect the inner $\epsilon$-collar. This implies that the inner collar is contained in the set difference $B \setminus (1-\epsilon/r(B))B$, which has volume $(1 - (1-\epsilon/r(B))^d)|B|$. Noting that $(1 - (1-\epsilon/r(B))^d) \leq ((1 + \epsilon/r(B))^d - 1)$ since the function $f(x)=x^d$ is convex, this completes the proof.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've added a paragraph to handle the inner collar, not exactly proving that the inner collar is smaller than the outer one, but proving that it satisfies the same bound as the outer collar, which is  enough to complete the proof.